# Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources' when building Application for Android

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript

When trying to build/run my NativeScript app on Android I keep getting an error. I already tried removing the platform and readding it and also remove all node_modules and added them again. The iOS-Version runs perfectly fine, its just the Android version having troubles atm.

My App.gradle:

```
android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = %my_projectname%
  }  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
  dependencies {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                details.useVersion '26.0.+'
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

From my package.json:

```
"nativescript": {
    "id": %my_projectname%,
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.1.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    }
  }
```

The error:

```
14:04:01.299 [QUIET] [system.out] Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
14:04:01.301 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
14:04:01.302 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'
14:04:01.302 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources FAILED
14:04:01.302 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 5.389 secs.
14:04:01.302 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationWorkerRegistry] Worker root.45 completed (0 in use)
14:04:01.303 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]] finished, busy: 32.075 secs, idle: 0.116 secs
14:04:01.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:04:01.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:04:01.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:04:01.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:04:01.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.
14:04:01.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
14:04:01.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:04:01.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
14:04:01.305 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.
14:04:01.305 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
14:04:01.305 [ERROR] 
....
14:04:01.319 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.out(AaptProcess.java:215)
14:04:01.319 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$2.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:143)
14:04:01.319 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:04:01.319 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
14:04:01.319 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
14:04:01.319 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
14:04:01.320 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 57.585 secs
14:04:01.333 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for task history cache (C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts)
14:04:01.334 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskArtifacts.bin (C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin)
14:04:01.335 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\fileHashes.bin)
14:04:01.335 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts\fileSnapshots.bin)
14:04:01.335 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (C:\Dev\biff\HandyApp\platforms\android\.gradle\3.3\taskArtifacts).
14:04:01.336 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
14:04:01.337 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 4 (avg: 0.017 secs, total: 0.071 secs)
14:04:01.337 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.002 secs
14:04:01.337 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin Resolution Cache (C:\Users\frr\.gradle\caches\3.3\plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.
14:04:01.338 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.daemon.WorkerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 worker daemon(s).
14:04:01.338 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.daemon.WorkerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
14:04:01.338 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Generated Gradle JARs cache (C:\Users\frr\.gradle\caches\3.3\generated-gradle-jars) was closed 0 times.
14:04:01.338 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess] Releasing file lock for artifact cache (C:\Users\frr\.gradle\caches\modules-2)
14:04:01.338 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (C:\Users\frr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\artifact-at-repository.bin)
14:04:01.338 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (C:\Users\frr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\module-metadata.bin)
14:04:01.338 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-artifacts.bin (C:\Users\frr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\module-artifacts.bin)
14:04:01.338 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-versions.bin (C:\Users\frr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\module-versions.bin)
14:04:01.338 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (C:\Users\frr\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
14:04:01.339 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has finished executing the build.
14:04:11.602 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientInputForwarder] Dispatching close input message: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput@2e425d92
14:04:18.343 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 14: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.CloseInput
14:04:18.346 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1F2F3DebugResources'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=6744, address=[c1153b93-8604-4b5b-acb4-2dd6530b37a1 port:49887, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1504872097503, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=5919326b-2ad7-481d-93a3-189f8cd671ee,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\frr\.gradle\daemon,pid=6744,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx16384M,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=DE,-Duser.language=de,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
14:04:18.346 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished
14:04:18.349 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: connection stop
Error: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.childProcess.on
```

UPDATE:----------------------------------------------------

From my Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>
 <application
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
```

I use as the launch screen a splash_screen.png.

From my styles.xml:

```
<style name="LaunchScreenThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/NativeScriptToolbarStyle</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ns_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ns_primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ns_accent</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

The error is only occuring, when I swap the `splash_screen.png`. I inserted the one I used in the old version and it worked perfectly well. in my `drawable-folders` I proved the `splash_screen.png` and the `icon.png` (the app icon). When I change the `icon.png` there is no problem, just the splash_screen seems to produce problems and I can't understand why.

Comment: maybe you can try to remove gradle? ```rm -rf ~/.gradle```

Comment: @ikhsan That did sadly not do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I used a nine-patch as launching screen for android that was not properly created/formatted as one. Creating one with Android Studio solved that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution to this problem:

gradle assemble -info gave me the hint that the Manifests have different SDK Versions and cannot be merged.

I needed to edit my Manifests and build.gradle file and everything worked again.

To be clear you need to edit the uses-sdk in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

and the android section, particularly minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in the build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Please check you have closed or not application tag . this is also the possible reason for this error :if not please use this :

```
</application>
```

I have seen your updated post . it seems a naming convention problem . please rename the image for all drawable folders and also check whether images are png or not in all drawable folders. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it, but it did not change the outcome, sadly. It seems to be nothing with my sdk-Version. I updated my post and added my actual Manifest.xml and some more information on how the error occured.

Comment: please check application tag is closed or not

Comment: Yep it is, like mentioned above: It works perfectly well (even the android version) if I do not update the splash_screen.png. I ensured it is formatted the same way - can there be any metdata saved he cannot merge?

Comment: do one thing delete splash_screen.png from all drawable folders then clean project . now rename the splash_screen.png and copy it again in all drawable and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: I tried around a bit. If i completely remove all the splash_screen png's I get the same error (and he says that he could not find that resource). If I readd the old ones it runs, if I add the new ones instead it fails again.